# Tracking a campaign with URI params in GA4

Tags: google-analytics

Once upon a time adding the following URL params to a URL would log a view in Google Analytics as a campaign, medium, and so on (note this is Facebook template):

```
?utm_source={{site_source_name}}&utm_medium={{placement}}&utm_campaign={{campaign.name}}_{{adset.name}}&utm_content={{ad.name}}
```

However, GA4 doesn't seem to be logging these as all. If I go to GA4's Acquisition -> Traffic Acquisition it does not have any views from campaigns logged. In UA's Acquisition -> Campaigns -> All Campaigns these were always logged.

Has the API changed for this (i.e. is `utm_source`, etc, not the way to do it anymore), or is this just broken? So far GA4 feels like a car crash and anyone creating a new account is put in the driving seat (can't create UA accounts anymore)!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question and belongs on [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 2):

In GA4's Traffic Acquisition report,

- `utm_source` populates the source dimension,
- `utm_medium` populates the medium dimension,
- `utm_campaign` populates the campaign dimension,
- `utm_content` does not populate a system-defined dimension today.

`utm_content` does populate the event parameter "content". You can register the event parameter "content" as an event-scoped custom dimension ([article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209)), and use that custom dimension in reports.

GA4's reporting does not have the same data freshness as UA. For standard GA4 properties, intraday data may be delayed by 4 to 8 hours. This means that GA4's Traffic Acquisition report will update with your `utm` URI parameters 4 to 8 hours after the pageviews were logged.

In GA4 Realtime, you can verify that your `utm` URI parameters are being logged. For example if you logged `?utm_source=some-source&utm_medium=some-medium&utm_campaign=some-campaign&utm_content=some-content`, then these source, medium, campaign, and content parameters are available on the page_view event in realtime.

In the GA4 Realtime report, select the `page_view` event:

[image: event count by event name]

Select the `medium` event parameter:

[image: page_view event parameters]

Notice the `some-medium` is consistent with the logged event.

[image: event parameter medium has value some-medium]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Facebook URL builder? If so, you CAN'T put the question mark as Facebook puts it automatically